# youtube api call function when video ends

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I need to find out when an embedded youtube video ends via javascript.

This is my embed code:

```
    <object id="ytplayer" height="35" width="560"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/u8C-ZTQJIkU?version=3&enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer&rel=0&fs=0&theme=light&showinfo=0&modestbranding=1&autohide=0&color=white">
    </param>
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="false">


    </param>
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">


    </param>
    <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/u8C-ZTQJIkU?version=3&rel=0&fs=0&theme=light&showinfo=0&modestbranding=1&autohide=0&color=white" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="false" width="560" height="35" allowscriptaccess="always"></embed></object>
```

---

This is the code I have so far to find out when it has ended but the alert doesnt come up. Could you help me find whats wrong?

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
      ytplayer = document.getElementById("ytplayer");
      ytplayer.addEventListener("onStateChange", "onytplayerStateChange");
    }

    function onytplayerStateChange(newState) {
       alert("Player's new state: " + newState);
    }
    </script>
```

Thank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have shown only part of the code. The **object** tag should contain an attribute called **id** that should be set to **ytplayer**. Here is the fully working code:

```
 <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="ytplayer" data="http://www.youtube.com/v/u8C-ZTQJIkU?enablejsapi=1&amp;playerapiid=ytplayer&amp;version=3" width="425" height="356"><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
</object>

</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.1/swfobject.js"></script>    

<script type="text/javascript">

    function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
        var player = document.getElementById("ytplayer");
        player.addEventListener("onStateChange", "onytplayerStateChange");
    }

    function onytplayerStateChange(newState) {
        alert("New state " + newState); 
    }

</script>
```

Comment: your code works however my embed code is different to what you are using and it does not work for mine.

Comment: I am sorry that your code did not work. Your method using embed is not a recommended option. Please refer to: http://www.bernzilla.com/item.php?id=681 Alternatively, please consider using iframe api: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference